# How to Customise Pandas Date Time Stamp @ x-axis

Tags: python, date, time, plot, pandas

When I plots the complete data works fine and displays the date on the x-axis:

[image: 1].

When I zoom into particular portion to view:
[image: 2]

the plot shows only the time rather than date, I do understand with less points can't display different set of date but how to show date or set date format even if the graph is zoomed?

```
dataToPlot = pd.read_csv(fileName, names=['time','1','2','3','4','plotValue','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'], 
                             sep=',', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
dataToPlot.drop(dataToPlot.index[0])
startTime = dataToPlot.head(1).index[0]
endTime = dataToPlot.tail(1).index[0]
ax = pd.rolling_mean(dataToPlot_plot[startTime:endTime][['plotValue']],mar).plot(linestyle='-', linewidth=3,  markersize=9, color='#FECB00')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a solution to make the labels look consistent, though bear in mind that it will also include the time on the "larger scale" time plot.

The code below uses the [`matplotlib.dates`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) functionality to choose a date format for the x-axis. Note that as we're using the matplotlib formatting you can't simple use `df.plot` but must instead use `plt.plot_date` and convert your index to the correct format.

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates

# Generate some random data and plot it

time = pd.date_range('07/11/2014', periods=1000, freq='5min')
ts = pd.Series(pd.np.random.randn(len(time)), index=time)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot_date(ts.index.to_pydatetime(), ts.data)

# Create your formatter object and change the xaxis formatting.

date_fmt = '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'

formatter = dates.DateFormatter(date_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

### An example showing the fully zoomed out plot

[image]

### An example showing the plot zoomed in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Ffisegydd when I tried got an error, which I had copied below your answer, please let me know what could be causing this error...Thanks

Comment: ax.plot_date(ts.index.to_pydatetime(), ts.data)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'plot_date'

Comment: Great Dr. It worked finally after removing the line ax = plt.subplots(), now it shows blue dotted lines on the zero axis [http://i.imgur.com/bUstJVH.png], please advice me how to disable or not plot. Thank you so much for your time...

Comment: Sorry Dr. I was so lazy, but now I have constructed the code according to my use. Thanks for the help

Comment: The ax.plot_date(ts.index.to_pydatetime(), ts.data) line causes an error. Changing it to this works: ax.plot_date(ts.index.to_pydatetime(), ts.data).